# ARM Undefined Instruction Because BL Changes To CPSID

Tags: assembly, arm

so I'm getting an undefined exception in an ARM microcontroller. I know why you are supposed to get those: you are loading an instruction in memory that doesn't exist for the mode you are in (ARM or Thumb), and then you have do to the R14 minus 2 to get the instruction etc. I read the ARM ARM, but it's not helping me.

Here what I'm seeing:

The compiled instruction loaded into memory should be F7FF which corresponds to a BL but my debugger is telling me that it's B7FF which is a CPSID. The weird thing is that this does not happen every time I run through that piece of code, only some times. What could be the problem?

This is what I'm using:

- Micro - AT91SAM7X512
- RTOS - uVelosity 2.2.8
- Compiler - MULTI v506

**Edit (Some more notes):**

R14_und = 0x2b02 every single time I hit this problem

[image: Register contents when undefined exception]

This is what should be the memory content (when I disassemble from the binary):

[image: Disassembly]

But this is what it is according to the debugger:

[image]

Almost any minor change in my code "fixes" the problem.

If I change the RTOS to a newer version (2.2.9) that also "fixes" the problem.

This also only happens with some microcontrollers but not all (I have four of the exact same lot number)

**Edit 2:**

I have dumped the flash contents and they look good and match my binary.

[image: Flash dump of 0x2b00]

**Edit 3**

- Static code analysis looks good

**Edit 4**

I can make changes in my C source code that don't get executed and the issue goes away.

** Edit 5 **

I'm using a 55MhZ clock (so my Periodic Interval Timer is set to 342). The datasheet sheet says I can use a wait state of 1, 2, and 3 but the errata says 3.  Did they forget to update the first table or is that common practice? To note the errors in the errdata while leaving everything else the same.

**Datasheet Wait State Table:**

[image: Wait state table]

**Errata Table:**
[image: Errata Wait State TAble]

http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel_32-bit-ARM7TDMI-Flash-Microcontroller_SAM7X512-256-128_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: memory overwrite? Check your debugger, if you can set up breakpoint on memory write, and then set it up after the `BL` is in place... I you don't have memory breakpoints, then probably put a breakpoint somewhere to break the app often enough, and keep watching the memory yourself, trying to guess what may be the trigger to change that value.

Comment: Might be the debugger causing this not the program itself.  Does this only happen when you are using the debugger, breakpoints or single stepping, etc?  Is this instruction in ram or flash?

Comment: @Ped7g I don't get a breakpoint on writes. But I put a breakpoint to break when the instruction in memory was not equal to what the debugger read and got a break point. Here is another strange thing: This only happens in some PCBs (all of which have the exact same microcontroller down to the lot number) and it's always the same line of code.

Comment: @old_timer The behavior is the same when I remove the debugger. Of course I can't see the actual contents without it, but the behavior is the same. Yes, it's in flash.

Comment: Any instruction with bits[15:12] = 1011, and which is not shown in Figure 6-2, is an undefined instruction.   for the ARM7TDMI this is actually an undefined instruction not a CPSID.  you CAN see without the debugger, you can dump the flash out and compare it to what you wrote.  it still looks like the debugger put this there, but this is in theory flash not ram so that would be very strange indeed.

Comment: there is only one bit difference between 0xF7FF and 0xB7FF, so it could be bit rot or something else.  ideally this flash would fail high not fail low, so that means you could have a write somewhere else in your code (or by the debugger) that is hitting this address. erasing makes it ones, but writes you can do on a smaller scale generally, and sometimes multiple passes on flash/rom items to make more individual zeros from ones.  Program the flash, dump/verify the flash, run without a debugger, stop, dump/verify the flash, what do you see.

Comment: this should have a SAM-BA debugger built in which is fairly trivial to write your own or find a generic SAM-BA tool (without using a full blown debugger) with which to independently verify the contents of the flash.

Comment: @old_timer I have dumped the flash and compared it to the binary and it looks good (they match bit by bit) and they are not that wrong instruction I see.  I have also done memory reading tests that come with my IDE (basically 1000s of reads on memory regions) and they all pass.

Comment: @old_timer I have several chips of the same lot and also different lots.  I have really new ones (17th week of 2016) and really old ones (2000's), different Revs and they all have this problem but only some i.e. I have chips that never hit this issue and it's really really simple to reproduce.

Comment: what is your flash wait state set to?  is it set appropriate for the pll/clock setting?  what if you increase it or max it out?

Comment: I would lean toward it is something you are doing to the chip rather than the chip, and not to say that in a mean way.  there is a bug somewhere a timing issue.  I doubt read disturb, but flash wait states could very well do it but usually not this consistently in the same location which leads to software corrupting the flash but you say the flash isnt corrupt.  chip production problems wouldnt have this one bit in one address flip, that doesnt make sense.  This is a good one I hope you find it.

Comment: as well as the wait states or slowing the clock if possible for your application  (or speeding it up).  if you add one or a few nops to the bootstrap code or in some way add stuff to the front of the binary so that the alignment changes for the rest of the binary does the problem follow the address or the instruction or move somewhere else all together (or go away).  Likewise if you change the optimization level that will move and change the code possibly quite a bit, does the problem hit the same memory location, go away, etc...

Comment: I might go so far as to write a directed test that puts this instruction in that address but the test just pounds on that instruction, a few dozen instructions total or whatever is needed a loop around this instruction with the place it calls simply returning, maybe add the prior and following instructions as well working each direction.  but increase the pain on that area and then perhaps the called functions take more time and reduce the pain.  If for example you isolate this instruction sequence and neuter what they call with returns, do that in a loop and it doesnt fail then

Comment: what you are seeing is that some other code or logic is leaving a land mine and this is they symptom, the stepping on the land mine, you need to find the placing of the land mine that can be anywhere....you have a "good one" on your hands which is an unfortunately bad term for something that is causing this much pain.

Comment: we just had one that took two months to find, was a gcc plus specific arm core nuance issue in the end, but we used terms like "excited" and "good one" and others.  the junior engineer doing most of the work on that one matured greatly in his skills, came up with some impressive hand made debugging tools to attack a specific binary (change the code even a little and the problem moves or goes away, which feels like a compiler or timing bug, but wasnt it was if you create the right data pattern after a specific instruction thing).

Comment: I dont think the ARM7TDMI had a cache itself doesnt mean chip vendors couldnt add one.  From high level feature list it says there is a prefetch buffer associated with the flash, when it fails, you may be getting this bit flip between the flash and the buffer, the buffer still has the data when the debugger trips?  I dont know, point being if there is a ram documented or undocumented that the chip is using to cache-like hold data, you might do the fetch and fail, then the debugger reads the ram and gets this cached copy not the real copy,

Comment: @old_timer That is EXACTLY what this one feels like, I've been at it for 2 weeks putting in 15+ hrs per day, reading all the ARM ARM etc (it's an interesting problem to have but there are project deadlines). And yes, it does look like it's a "right data pattern after a specific instruction" problem. I'm looking into how to make that "right data pattern" right now to prove it. Almost out of options right now. Thanks for all the help and ideas!

Comment: if so can you be cleaver with the debugger to dump/read other areas of flash, then come back to this area and see if the debugger still sees the bit flipped (cause the debugger to do a fresh read of actual flash).  if you instrument the undefined instruction handler to read the faulted address fairly quickly, does it show the same data that the debugger sees later when you use it?

Comment: well like I said in too many words, with the ease at which it happens and the number of different chips you can can produce it with, it smells like the way the chip is being treated, either software bug somehow doing something to some logic causing this fetch and then later reads with the debugger to get a bit flip (but then a whole dump doesnt see the flip, does that make sense, did you dump it with the debugger after the fault?).   Maybe it is another systemic thing, are you starving the power on the board or to the chip, do you have enough bulk capacitance, etc.

Comment: is the peripheral you are talking to around that time (or whatever touching on chip or on board) causing a current spike?  are you using a bench supply and have the current limit to tight not allowing for inrush current to be satisfied?  Or is it simple timing, clocks to fast for something in the chip, flash doesnt have the correct wait states for the system clock speed, etc.

Comment: so, you get a fault, then you look at it with the debugger and see this bit flip turning a bl into an undefined, the core read the location (fetch) saw the flip, then at some point later the debugger did a data read of the location, and see what we see above?  THEN if you dump or keep reading it or a bunch of the flash, with the debugger first and other tools later, the bit fixes itself or remains flipped until a power cycle or other such thing?  trying to initially understand how the debugger even sees this flipped bit as it should be a second read of the location, but a dump doesnt

Comment: @old_timer Our Periodic Interval Timer is set so that it operates at 55MhZ (the value is 342 decimal). I think you might be right about that the wait states could be wrong, here's what I have: The wait state we use is "1", according to table 38-25 of the datasheet, 1, 2, and 3 can be used for 55Mhz BUT according to the erradata Table 41-2 it should be 3. Did they leave the wrong table in the datasheet? Which table is correct? I'm going to try a wait state of 3 while I found out. Datasheet: http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel_32-bit-ARM7TDMI-Flash-Microcontroller_SAM7X512-256-128_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: other than code performance more waitstates cant hurt.  fewer most definitely can as the data read from the flash will be corrupt.